# How to find manually the value of the likelihood function?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I have a statistic homework and this is my question:

Outcome (binary)=f(age, number of books)

And that I have four observations in my dataset:

- Observation 1: Outcome=1, age=0.5, number of books=5
- Observation 2: Outcome =0, age =2, number of books =20
- Observation 3: Outcome =1, age =2, number of books =3
- Observation 4: Outcome =0, age =1, number of books =18

Outcome = it is the probability.

This is my question :

> What is the value of the likelihood function $L(b_0,b_1,b_2)$ if we let $b_0=-0.75, b_1=-0.03,b_2=0.01$? Estimate the likelihood manually, and show your work below.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you please clarify what is bo, b1 and b2?

Comment: You might recognize this as logistic regression.  What is the likelihood function for logistic regression?  What does it assume the outcome is distributed like?

Comment: @StatsPlease I am not sure I follow. What is Yi? I should do the product of what? Do I have to do the sum of something for each observation?

Comment: @Zach I've added some further detail, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

So what you have is a logistic regression model, where $\boldsymbol\beta$ are your regression coefficients and $\boldsymbol X$ is your data. Now, the likelihood function for your model is:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{4}\text{Pr}(Y=y_{i}\,|\,X=x_{i})=\prod_{i=1}^{4}p(x_{i};\boldsymbol\beta)^{y_{i}}\big(1-p(x_{i};\boldsymbol\beta)\big)^{1-y_{i}}$$

where $y_{i}\in\{0,1\}$ is your outcome.

Now, what you are being asked to do is to evaluate the likelihood function given the parameters and data. So what this means is, to take the likelihood function and input the data and the parameter values you've been given using the function you'd originally provided (with a small correction)

$$
\begin{align}
p(x_i;\boldsymbol\beta)&=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-b_{0}-b_{1}\cdot x_{1,i}-b_{2}\cdot x_{2,i})}\\
\end{align}$$

So, for example, for $i=1$ (your first observation)

$$
\begin{align}
p(x_1;\boldsymbol\beta)&=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-b_{0}-b_{1}\cdot x_{1,1}-b_{2}\cdot x_{2,1})}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\exp(0.75+0.03\times 0.5-0.01\times5)}\\
&\approx 0.3285
\end{align}$$